# Python, issue with for loop and List can't figure it out

Tags: python, list, sorting, loops, for-loop

This is from codecademy, it keeps telling me that `square_list` isn't the same length as `start_list` (it needs to be) and it also doesn't sort it even tho I am calling sort onto `square_list` (have to call it on `square_list` can't do it with `start_list`)

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

square_list.append(start_list)
square_list.sort()

for start_list in square_list:   
    print square_list
```

Comment: You have several oddities and mistakes here. I suggest going back and rereading the lessons you didn't fully understand.

Comment: why are you creating the second list? Also I imagine you want extend not append

Comment: it tells me to do so

Comment: what is the objective of this practice ?

Comment: all i did was .append() , .sort() and the loop the rest as given to me

Comment: you are appending a single list to an empty list, by definition a list with one element is already sorted

Comment: Write a for-loop that iterates over start_list and .append()s each number squared (x ** 2) to square_list.
Then sort square_list!

Comment: where are you doing `x**2`?

Comment: i just added it after, was just trying to get it to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append()` function call in this case appends the entire list `start_list` to the `square_list` which would result in something like `[[5, 3, 1, 2, 4]]`. Use the + operator to concatenate the lists:

```
square_list = square_list + start_list
```

You can also create a list comprehension like this:

```
square_list = [n for n in start_list]
```

If you *have* to use the `append()` function, then do something like:

```
for n in start_list:
    square_list.append(n)
```

However, this isn't the pythonic way and list comprehensions are used to avoid something like this.

Comment: one of the requirements is to use the .append() method, how could I do this and still use .append() ?

Comment: Edited my answer for that

Comment: It works ,It's a beginner python course I'm sure they are gonna cover better practices ...hopefully

Comment: List comprehensions also allow you to do whatever computations you want. So if you want squares, you can do: `square_list = [n ** 2 for n in start_list]`

Answer (score 0):

Q:  Write a for-loop that iterates over start_list and .append()s each number squared (x ** 2) to square_list. Then sort square_list!

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

# loop start_list
for element in start_list:
    # append each element**2 to square_list
    square_list.append(element**2)
# sort the list.
square_list.sort()
```

Comment: thanks this code did it, besides that i had to add (element**2) for the excise

Comment: make sure to read the course material before posting on SO. people of SO hate this kind of question.